# Is it possible to return System.Type from COM interop in .net 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop

I have a class:

```
public class A
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Type t = icom.ReturnType;
    }
}

[ComVisible(true),
Guid("81C99F84-AA95-41A5-868E-62FAC8FAC263"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface Icom
{
    Type ReturnType { get; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("6DF6B926-8EB1-4333-827F-DD814B868097")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(Icom))]
public class B : Icom
{
    public Type ReturnType
    {
        get
        {
            return SomeAssembly.GetType("fullname");
        }
    }
}
```

Is this somehow possible to accomplish in .NET 3.5? My goal is to return `System.Type` from class B. In this case I receive an error that Unable to cast `System.__Com` to `System.Type`.

Comment: Why is it specific to .NET 3.5, does it work for you with 4.5? What line exactly gives you that error? What's the type of `SomeAssembly` (are you sure it's [Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.Assembly.aspx))? It would also help if you tell us what you are trying to achieve, in general.

Comment: Because it works in 4.5 and class A is in project that is built on 3.5. Type t = icom.ReturnType is the line that gives me an error. For example I need to return this Type: return                 LoadedAssembly.GetType(                    "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.DbMaintenanceTSQLExecuteTask"); where LoadedAssembly is MaintenancePlanTasks dll that has been previously loaded. I just didn't wrote a code for loading that assembly since it's already in an array but I hope you can see what I need to return.

Comment: Also MaintenancePlanTasks is .net 4.0 dll. That's why class B is in .net 4.0 project because I can load those assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain what's going on, as I understand it. It appears you have the following workflow of calls (or objects being passing over): .NET 4.x -> COM -> .NET 3.5. Your `Icom` interface is marshaled to COM like this (OleView):

```
[
  odl,
  uuid(81C99F84-AA95-41A5-868E-62FAC8FAC263),
  version(1.0),
  dual,
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "InteropTest.Icom")    

]
interface Icom : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000), propget]
    HRESULT ReturnType([out, retval] _Type** pRetVal);
};
```

Note the `_Type` which is unmanaged proxy for managed `Type` class, implemented in `mscorlib.dll` (type library `mscorlib.tlb`). Its implementation is specific to each .NET Runtime version. Apparently, it gets created by .NET Runtime v4.0.

At some point later, you're trying to un-marshal it back, this time on .NET 3.5 side. If it was v4.0, you'd get back the same managed `Type` object. However, with v3.5 you are getting an unamaged `System.__ComObject`, which cannot be converted to v3.5 managed `Type` object.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Ok, thanks for explanation. It was very helpful.